# VBA code compiling with an invalid qualifier error

Tags: excel, vba

This is basic VBA here that I need help with,
I am creating a `userForm` that takes peoples entries and places there input into the next free cell in a column on a `sheet (sheet3)`.
the input i'm asking to add here is, i have an label that gives out an integer,
however i'm always getting the compile error. `"Invalid qualifier"` and i'm not sure why. I have done this before and succeeded but this time it's confusing me what i'm missing.
hope someone can help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


    Dim vendorNumLabel As String
    Dim eRow As Integer

    'adding the value of the textboxes to the assigned variables

    vendorNumLabel = Me.VendorNumberLBL.Caption


    ' working out next empty row

    eRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row



    'applying values to cells in regards to the empty row worked out above.

    Sheet3.Cells(eRow, 3) = vendorNumLabel.Text


    Unload Me


End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing the definition of `eRow` to `eRow As Long`. Also, it should be `Sheet3.Cells(eRow, 3) = vendorNumLabel `

Comment: What line is indicated in the error?

Comment: `vendorNumLabel` is a String and does not have `Text` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim vendorNumLabel As String
Dim eRow As Integer

vendorNumLabel = Me.VendorNumberLBL.Text    
eRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row    
Sheet3.Cells(eRow, 3).Value = vendorNumLabel


Unload Me


End Sub
```